# Nest JS: Using Node AsyncLocalStorage inside Nest Pipes

Tags: nestjs

I am planning to use the NestJS Pipe for storing some app specific information through AsyncLocalStorage of Node JS. (Node version is 18.x).

I am planning to mimic the [Nest JS Request Context](https://github.com/abonifacio/nestjs-request-context) to store app-specific request context.

For that I need to adhere to the [AsyncStorage Run method](https://nodejs.org/api/async_context.html#asynclocalstoragerunstore-callback-args).

Something like this:

```js
import {ArgumentMetadata, Injectable, PipeTransform} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { MyRequestContext } from './my-request-context.model';

@Injectable()
export class RequestContextPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor() {}  // any services can be injected here

    async transform(publicId: string, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
        // Here we will have logic which will get the various values we want to set in the RequestContext. Lets call that as appContext.
        // MyRequestContext.cls.run(new MyRequestContext(req, res, appContext), next);

    }
}
```

```js
import { AsyncLocalStorage } from 'async_hooks';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

export class MyRequestContext {
  static cls = new AsyncLocalStorage<RequestContext>();

  static get currentContext() {
    return this.cls.getStore();
  }

  constructor(public readonly req: Request, public readonly res: Response, public readonly appContext: AppData) {}
}
```

But the problem I am facing:

How to get the request, response and next inside a Nest JS pipe?

I want to execute this line of code inside NestJS Pipe's `transform` method:

```js
     MyRequestContext.cls.run(new MyRequestContext(req, res, appContext), next);
```

So I need the `request`, `response` and `next` inside the Pipe.

How may I get it?

Comment: "storing some app specific information" — that's not what pipes are for, you probably want an interceptor instead. Either way, have you already tried injecting the request etc into the pipe? This, of course, means the pipe should be request scoped as well, but it definitely works.

Comment: Yes. Interceptor is an option.
But what do you meant by injecting requests etc?
for interceptor those are inside the context (ExecutionContext).

Comment: I mean this one:
      let request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
But how can I get the context in Pipe, if possible.

Comment: By "injecting requests" I mean the reason you marked the pipe as `@Injectable` and wrote a comment `// any services can be injected here`: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes

Comment: Ok. got it. I meant that for other App services, which will be used for calculation of our metaData.

Comment: So far then looks like Interceptor may be best suited for this purpose. Tha's what I think we are getting.
Please correct if I am wrong.